# Going from a parent form to a child form without creating a gcnew form

Tags: c++-cli

Hello I have a main form (Form1) and a child form (Form5). If I click a button for the first time I want it to open a new form. However if it is being clicked for the second time I want it to open the form I opened the first time, holding that forms data I will have filled in (textboxes etc). This is what I have:
.cpp file:

```
System::Void Form1::button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e){
formclick++;

if (formclick == 1)

{
      Form5 ^dos1 = gcnew Form5(this, MyArray, MyArray1);

    dos1->Show();
}

if (formclick==2)
{


            otherform->Show();
}
```

Form1.h file:

```
>   Form1(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ Form5)
>         {
>           
>           
>               otherform = Form5;
>             InitializeComponent();
>         }         public: System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ otherform;
```

However I get the error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

TIA

Comment: That constructor you wrote is never used, so "otherform" will always be nullptr.  Kaboom of course.  Create a new object when it is nullptr.  You need to subscribe the FormClosed event to reliably set it back to nullptr.  And implement FormClosing in Form5 to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the newly created form in the local scope of the button5_click function (in the `dos1` variable) and that means it is free to be removed from memory when the function exists.

The code excerpts you've given is a little messy, but it could be enough for you to change the click funtion to the following:

```
 System::Void Form1::button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e){
   if (!otherForm) 
     otherForm = gcnew Form5(this, MyArray, MyArray1);
   else
     otherform->Show();
 }
```

Code not tested, but the principal thing is that you need to store the newly created form in a class member, and not only locally to the click funtion!

Regards
Even

Comment: Thanks for that Holroy, that worked! I was wondering if I wanted to automatically fill in some boxed on the click in form 5 how would I do that?

Comment: For example
otherform->checkedListBox1->Items->Add(gcnew String(buffer));

Comment: Glad it helped. Your comment is another question, which could use a separate question here on Stack Overflow. However you might get some hints from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/196341/CheckList-Box-and-List-Box). Your code, as it seems, would/could add a new item to the check list in the otherForm. Please use comments to comment, not ask new questions! :-)